# Windows Vim symlink config file persistent error

Tags: windows, vim, cygwin, symbolic-link, vimrc

I'm trying to configure the native Windows Vim/gVim and the Cygwin Vim/gVim to behave nicely together. To this end, I created symlinks, `~/.vimrc` and `C:\Users\<myusername>\_vimrc`, that both point to a common `vimrc` file containing my actual shared Vim configuration. (I did a similar trick with another config file that is sourced by my `vimrc`.) (Note that `$HOME` is `C:\Users\<myusername>`, so the above links are in the same directory; I just wanted to emphasize that one is used by Cygwin while the other is used by the Windows-native Vim.) The `.vimrc` file was created using `ln -s` in Cygwin, while the `_vimrc` file was created using the `mklink` Windows command.

This worked fine until I moved the location of the actual `vimrc` file to which the links point. I faithfully corrected the Cygwin and Windows symlinks; now Cygwin gVim correctly finds the rc file, but Windows gives the following error:

First, A command-prompt window pops up with the following message:

```
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c <symlink> ■p
The system cannot find the file specified.
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

When I hit a key, that window closes and a little gVim pop-up window appears with the following message, which I assume is the Vim command that causes the problem:

```
:!<symlink><ff><fe>p
```

When I close this window, gVim starts correctly, *with the correct settings from my vimrc file*. This last part boggles my mind somewhat, because I think it means that the `_vimrc` symlink is actually configured correctly--but if that's the case, why am I still getting an error?

Now, some notes:

- When I first moved the `vimrc` file, my "correction" to the Windows symlink was to make it point to the Cygwin symlink. The error messages shown were the same, but when gVim finally started it did *not* load the configuration from the `vimrc` file.
- I tried deleting the Windows symlinks entirely; I also tried uninstalling and re-installing the native gVim. Neither of these changed the behavior.
- I see there are a couple other questions about using a setup somewhat like this, but I don't see any describing a problem very similar to mine.

Comment: I had been getting this error for a month whenever I launched gVim in Winblows. I had already replaced my usual Cygwin symlinks with copies to get rid of it, including for ~/.vimrc. It continued to haunt me until I thought to search the file system for remaining symlinks... And that's when I realized that I had forgotten about ~/.gvimrc. Maybe that'll save somebody some time and frustration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was about the dumbest fix I've ever seen. Launching gVim from the command line and manually specifying `-u C:\Users\<myusername>\_vimrc` not only prevented the error messages from popping up that time, it has apparently fixed my setup so that no matter how I launch Vim I no longer see the error messages described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but posting just in case it helps:

Possibly related to the down-voted post above, I had similar issues in Windows 10 that I resolved by making sure that the Windows `%HOME%` environment variable pointed to a folder that contained a `_vimrc` file.

I documented my trials, travails, and hacked solution here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20076/windows-context-menu-open-with-vim-symlink-error/20098#20098.

Am now able to launch gvim.exe from a cmd shell or via Explorer `Edit with Vim` context menu.

Answer (score -2):

I used to have the same problem here. Using the [rapid environment editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/download) I figure out that a variable `HOME` was set to `c:/cygwin/home/%user%` under Windows environment:

[image]

After I removed this variable from Windows environment, gvim run without the problem.

Comment: You *removed* your `HOME` variable? That should break quite a few Cygwin programs; in Linux it's generally assumed that you have a valid `$HOME` at all times.

Comment: I removed the `HOME` variable from Windows, but not inside cygwin.

Comment: My hint solve the following annoying problem when I tried to use context menu to open files.
`C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c <symlink> ■p
The system cannot find the file specified.
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...`
I understand that this does not solve the original question and I understand the motivation of the negative vote. Thank you for the maintain this site useful.